# Use LINQ to compare two List based on the same class

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a class named User:

```
 public class User
    {
        public int usedId { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }
    }
```

If I have two Lists based on this class:

```
 List<User> signIn = new List<User>();
 List<User> signOut = new List<User>();
```

How can I get a list of the substractions between the signIn list time property and the signOut list time property when the userId is the same? For example if the signIn list has userId= 30 with time= 20 at any point in the list and signOut list has userId= 30 (same as signIn) with time 40, how can I add the substraction (40-20) to a list using linq when the userIds are the same?

Comment: Do you want subtraction only for one item or for all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join them, which is probably more readable in query syntax:

```
var inout = from i in signIn
            join o in signOut on i.UserId equals o.UserId
            select new { i.UserId, Diff = o.Time - i.Time }
```

Method syntax for some LINQ operations is pretty unwieldy - I'm usually a method syntax person but I do prefer query syntax for joins. There are some good blog posts out there if you search for *query vs method LINQ*, that show them side by side .

Don't forget you can flip between them if you need to, such as putting the whole query in brackets and calling .Distinct() or .ToList() on it, like `var x = (from ... select ...).ToList();`

Be careful to ensure that each of your lists only contain unique UserId or you'll get unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two lists and calculate the difference:

```
var diff = signIn.Join(signOut, x => x.usedId, x => x.usedId, (signin,signout) => new { signout.usedId, diff = signout.time - signin.time }).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/44EmTo

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to combine items from two tables, based on a common value (like an Id), consider to use one of the overloads of (Group-)Join.

[Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin) is used if you want "items with their zero or more sub-items", like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, etc. The Id in one table is used by several Ids in the other table. For instance, all Students of School [10] have a foreign key with value 10, indicating that they attend School [10].

[Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join) is used if every item from one table has exactly one item from another table: Every Order is the Order of exactly one Customer. There are no Orders without Customers.

Whether you should use Join or GroupJoin depends on:

- Are there Signins without SignOut? (people are still working)
- Are there Signins with more than one SignOut?
- What do you want with SignOuts that have no matching Signin? Or don't they exist?

### Every SignIn has one SignOut

Let's assume the easy one: every Signin has exactly one Signout: we use a Join to find the Signouts that match the Signins. Use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector to define the result per matching [SignIn, SignOut] combination.

```
var result = signIns.Join(signOuts,

    signIn => signIn.UsedId,        // from every signIn take the UsedId
    signOut => signOut.UsedId,      // from every signOut take the UsedId

    // parameter resultSelector: whenever the UsedIds match, use the [signIn, signOut]
    // combination to make one new:
    (signIn, signOut) => new
    {
        UsedId = signIn.UsedId,
        TimeWorked = signOut.Time - signIn.Time,
    });
```

Side remark: try to stick to the conventions: collections are plural nouns, elements from collections are singular nouns. This way it will be way easier to detect what an identifier represents.

### There are Signins without SignOut, or with several SignOuts

You have to decide what to fill in if there is no SignOut yet (people still working), or if there are several SignOuts (people made mistakes when signing out.

In this case Use GroupJoin. The syntax is similar to Join.

```
var result = signIns.GroupJoin(signOuts,

    signIn => signIn.UsedId,        // from every signIn take the UsedId
    signOut => signOut.UsedId,      // from every signOut take the UsedId

    // parameter resultSelector: from every SignIn with its zero or more SignOuts
    // make one new:
    (signIn, signOutsOfThisSignIn) => new
    {
        UsedId = signIn.UsedId,

        ...
    });
```

What do you want if several SignOuts? Take the last one? = take the largest time?
If you are certain there is always at least one SignOut, you can use Max:

```
TimeWorked = signOutsOfThisSignIn.Select(signOut => signOut.time).Max();
```

If there might be SignIns without SignOuts, you can't use Max. You'll have to OrderBy, or use Aggregate to find the MaxOrDefault.

```
SignOutTime = signOutsOfThisSignIn.OrderByDescending(signOut => signOut.Time)
                                 .Select(signOut => signOut.time)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Using Aggregate might be more efficient: if you only want the first element, why bother to order the other elements? But Aggregate is maybe to much for this question.

By the way, what do you want if no SignOut? null?

In an extra Select

```
TimeWorked = (SignOutTime != null) ? (siginInTime - SignOuttime) : null;
```